# Not found/ or can't access root folder php with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The problem:
At the moment my webpage just shows the result but as random place and google.js won't start. If i troubleshoot in concole, it shows no game_statistics.inc found. But it is there. Can it be access problem, because js file is in web folder and game_statistic.inc is folder above access? How to fix it? How should I echo results in html file, to be where I want it?

client/src/sms/gamestatistics.inc file

```
$GAnalytics = "SELECT GAnalyticsEST, GAnalyticsRUS FROM GAME_game WHERE id = ".$GID." ; ";
$res= mysql_query($GAnalytics);
$resul = array();
while  ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
array_push($resul, array('GAnalyticsEST' => $row[0], 'GAnalyticsRUS' => $row[1] ));
echo json_encode(array("resul"=>$resul));
```

client/web/google.js code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 done();
});

function done() {
  setTimeout( function() { 
  updates(); 
  done();
  }, 9000);
}

function updates() {
 $.getJSON( '../src/sms/game_statistics.inc', function(data) {
       $("ul").empty();
   $.each(data.resul, function(){
    $("ul").append("<li>GoogleEST: "+this['GAnalyticsEST']+"</li><li>GoogleRUS:  "+this['GAnalyticsRUS']+"</li><br />");
   });
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get access to that because it's in a folder that isn't accessible to the web. If your browser can't get to it, the javascript being executed by the browser can't either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PHP to access things outside the Apache installation. So either move that php file to the Apache www dir, or make a script to include it

```
<?php require_once('../../file_outside_www.php'); ?>
```